# Oracle, How to filter duplicated row data?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

The table has 30+ columns and there are many duplicated row data like this:

```
col_1  col_2  col_3
1      2      2
2      3      2
1      2      2
3      2      2
1      2      2
2      3      2
3      2      2
```

I want to select all data and filter these duplicated rows, after filtering, the result is

```
col_1  col_2  col_3
1      2      2
2      3      2
3      2      2
```

I found `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` work but I should type many column names. Are there any easier methods available?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns)

Comment: @HồngVănVít, The answers from the link you provided don't work for me, `distinct * ` is what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

easiest way

```
select distinct * from table
```

or

```
select distinct col_1, col_2, col_3 from table
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Przemo answer, you better use `select distinct * from table`,

You can similarly  use `select unique * from table`

> Specify DISTINCT or UNIQUE if you want the database to return only one copy of each set of duplicate rows selected.

But not in Group by,

Group by can't be used with `*`, You [must specific column names](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/ref/rrefsqlj32654.html):

> GROUP BY 
>   {
>     column-Name [ , column-Name ]*
>
> column-Name must be a column from the current scope of the query

Comment: Hi, how can I improve the performance of `DISTINCT` since there are 100,000,000+ rows, it takes a long time to get the result.

Comment: Performance is a different question which you need to add more data on table and explain plan...

Comment: Thank you, I hope Oracle has a mechanism like MapReduce of Hadoop.